# pandas: .to_dict('records') resulting to odd keys

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `filtered_df` that looks like this:

```
suffix.3K  suffix.3K.R  suffix.CHAI  suffix.CHAI.R  suffix.CON  suffix.CON.R  suffix.ED  suffix.ED.R
123        1.0          1.0          1.0            1.0         1.0           1.0        1.0
```

I ran `filtered_df.to_dict('records')` and got the following results when I print it:

```
[{'_0': 1.0, '_1': 1.0, '_2': 1.0, '_3': 1.0, '_4': 1.0, '_5': 1.0, '_6': 1.0, '_7': 1.0, '_8': 299.0}]
```

Any idea why the resulted keys, which are supposed to be the column names, turned out to be like that? I tried changing the orientation and got the expected column names. I only experience this when `orient='records'`

Comment: when you do filtered_df.columns, can you see all the columns listed? Or do you see _1, _2

Comment: I printed them before running the `.to_dict()` and I can see the correct columns

Comment: Looks like this is a confirmed problem in pandas version `0.24.0` [df.to_dict('record') adds underscore to column names...](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24940#). Which version are you running?